# How to group data which have same Id number in SQL

Tags: sql, modulo

Query a list of CITY names from STATION for cities that have an even ID number. Print the results in any order, but exclude duplicates from the answer.

The STATION table is described as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE STATION
(
    Id int,
    CITY varchar(50),
    STATE varchar(50),
    LAT_N int,
    LONG_W int
)
```

I have this SQL which throws an error when I run:

```
SELECT CITY, STATE 
FROM STATION 
WHERE ID % 2 = 0 
GROUP BY ID, CITY, STATE
```

Comment: What error? That statement should not produce an error.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? If you are getting an error it may be because you are using a syntax not supported by your DBMS. The only likely operation for this would be the modulo operator. Does your DBMS support `%` for modulo? Are you supposed to select the state? Aren't the expected duplicates supposed to exist only because we neglect the state? You probably want to remove the `GROUP BY` clause and `SELECT DISTINCT city` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to group by ID

```
select CITY,STATE from STATION where (ID % 2)=0 group by CITY,STATE
```

But you don't need a grouping function, `DISTINCT` will do also the trick

```
select DISTINCT CITY, STATE from STATION where (ID % 2)=0
```