# Hi guys i'm an SQL beginner and i'm having a hard time understanding it could u explain this line for me

Tags: sql

SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE MOD(ID,2)=0 ORDER BY CITY ASC;

Comment: The statement is almost plain English; except for the `MOD(ID, 2) = 0` part, which means that `ID` must be an even number.

Comment: Maybe you should [collaborate with your fellow classmates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73013900/how-to-group-data-which-have-veen-id-number-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

#### `SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION`

- Primary command to select data from the database. It is asking to select `CITY` from the table `STATION` whose data is unique. Thus, no duplicates are produced in result.

#### `WHERE MOD(ID, 2) = 0`

- Only select those that have an even number `ID`.

#### `ORDER BY CITY`

- Sort the results with respect to `CITY` names.

#### `ASC`

- Sort in ascending order; which means that cities with names starting with `A` will come before those that have `Z` as first letter.